# Drupal - get the field of view

Tags: drupal-7

**Hello!**

I am trying to get the fields of views
There is a code:

```
$variables = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'news-block');   
print render($variables['content']);
```

to display unit software.

Whether it is possible to obtain the field at such a conclusion. Rather get views across the fields from variable `$variables`

Advance all grateful

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you want to customize the view of any particular field of your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`views_get_view_result`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) function:

```
$view = views_get_view_result($name, $display_id); // returns an array conatining the result of the view
print_r($view);
```

If you prefer to get whole node objects, you can use [`node_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7) function with nids of each row:

```
$view = views_get_view_result($name, $display_id); // returns an array conatining the result of the view
$nodes = array(); // create an empty array to push each node objects
foreach ($view as $row) {
    $node = node_load($row->nid); // get the node object by nid
    $nodes[] = $node; // push node to $nodes array
}
print_r($nodes);
```

Also see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32825/get-a-views-result-using-php-code-and-iterate-the-proper-way

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments!